# How to not extend the Object class in Java?

Tags: java, javac

By default, every class in Java extends the `Object` class. (So single inheritance always occurs)

Is there any class that does not extend Object class? (eg. int might be an instance of the class int but not an object)

Can we somehow create our own class that doesn't extend `Object`? Maybe by modifying `javac`'s final code to not extend Object class and maybe create our own class to surpass things that the constructor of the object class does at minimum to avoid abnormal behavior?

Comment: There is no 'dual inheritance'. You may extend soms user-defined class, which in turn has to extend Object down the line since that's the default. Your new class now also extends Object by inheritance. For example: A *is a* B which *is an* Object. So A is also an Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is a primitive, hence we cannot say it extends anything.

When it comes to your question:

> Is there any class that does not extend Object class?

You have answered it literally line above:

> every class in Java extends the Object class

P.S.: We cannot say, that there is a dual inheritance, because a class extends `Object` and some other class, because that "other class" also extends `Object`. In fact, a class is a subtype of all its supertypes, for example:

```
HashMap m = new LinkedHashMap();
AbstractMap m = new LinkedHashMap();
Object m = new LinkedHashMap();
```

Type parameters omitted for brevity.

Edit: referencing the discussion about what is an object and what is not, [JLS §4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) gives the answer:

> An object is a class instance or an array.

Comment: But I have heard that Java still keeps track of int as if it were a object (keeping it's background details) so can we say that `int` is an instance of class int but is not an object?

Comment: @Mr.Stackoverflow no, simply because there is no such class as `int`.

Comment: Also my second question...Going by theory the above questions practically look highly imaginary (dual inheritance) but they really aren't...There should be

Comment: So how does `System.out.println()` print an `int `alone? I mean saying that it is in-built could just be a guess..

Comment: There is an Integer class.

Comment: System.out.println("The number is "+3) is justified as it String+anything gets converted into a String

Comment: The only `class` that doesn't extend `Object` is `Object` itself

Comment: *Any* printing is converted to a String somewhere down the line

Comment: @Lino Point to be noted.

Comment: So is it possible to create a class without extending an object by modifying `javac`

Comment: Why would you ever do that?

Comment: To create a primitive type

Comment: @Mr.Stackoverflow you **can't** ever create a primitive type by yourself

Comment: I think even an array is a class, (.length) Are there any other members of this class?

Comment: @Mr.Stackoverflow see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html even arrays are of type `Object`

Comment: @Andronicus Is there any way to modify `javac`'s final code?

Comment: @Mr.Stackoverflow To do what you want, you will need to modify the JVM too, not just the generated .class files.